# Cannot connect USB webcam to computer through KVM switch?

Tags: usb, camera

I recently purchased a KVM switch ([this one](https://www.startech.com/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/2-Port-Dual-DVI-USB-KVM-Switch-with-Audio-20-Hub~SV231DD2DUA)) to allow me to use both my computers with one set of peripherals.  The device works in all respects (including on my usb keyboard and mouse) except I cannot connect my usb webcam ([this one](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826193061)) through the KVM.

After plugging the webcam into the switch I get the following from `dmesg`:

```
[ 1590.279218] usb 1-2.2: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[ 1590.360101] usb 1-2.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1590.567771] usb 1-2.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1590.775252] usb 1-2.2: device not accepting address 20, error -71
[ 1590.855265] usb 1-2.2: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[ 1590.935294] usb 1-2.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 1591.128087] usb 1-2.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1591.335839] usb 1-2.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1591.543261] usb 1-2.2: device not accepting address 21, error -71
[ 1591.623292] usb 1-2.2: new high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[ 1591.624139] usb 1-2.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1591.832161] usb 1-2.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1592.039339] usb 1-2.2: device not accepting address 22, error -71
[ 1592.119323] usb 1-2.2: new high-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[ 1592.120118] usb 1-2.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1592.327830] usb 1-2.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1592.535361] usb 1-2.2: device not accepting address 23, error -71
[ 1592.536058] usb 1-2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

The output from `uname -a` for my first system is

```
Linux gardener 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

for my second system it's

```
Linux antimony 4.13.0-45-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 30 11:18:27 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I should also know that the first system dual boots to Windows 7 and the webcam also does not work through the KVM there.  The webcam works on every system when it is not connected through the KVM.

Is the KVM simply incompatible with the webcam?

Comment: Did you try plugging the KVM switch into a USB 2.0 port?

Comment: As the USB webcam is not responding correctly during initialization, this very much looks like the KVM switch is not forwarding all USB packets correctly. For whatever reason.

Comment: Alternatives that might be possible for you are to plug the webcam into one system, then use *usbip* to make it available over the network to the 2nd system, or use *v4l2loopback* to duplicate the video stream and send that over the network.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It was plugged in to a usb 3.0 port.  I just switched it to a usb 2.0 port and the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

In a KVM, the USB ports for keyboard and mouse are often special: they might identify whether e.g. a mouse is being used as a plain old 2-button mouse, or with advanced features like scroll wheel and a larger number of buttons. The same mouse can used in different, incompatible modes by two computers connected to the same KVM.

The simplest way to deal with this would be for the KVM to present the mouse as "plugged in" only to the computer that actually has the KVM focus at the time. But when KVM focus is switched to another computer, this approach may cause a delay while the presence of the mouse is re-detected and the mouse protocol is re-initialized. Or if the system is running something other than a fully hot-plug-capable operating system (e.g. the system is within a BIOS setup menu), it might be necessary to reboot the system to re-detect the presence of the mouse. This is inconvenient.

As a result, some KVMs will attempt to detect and remember how each connected computer initialized their keyboard & mouse connections, and will maintain an illusion that the keyboard and mouse are still connected to the computer even when the KVM focus is switched away. When the KVM focus is switched back, the KVM will first replay the appropriate mouse initialization sequence to the mouse and only then resume the connection between the mouse and the computer. With the keyboard, such a KVM will remember & restore the state of the NumLock/CapsLock/ScrollLock LEDs with each KVM focus switch. When this works correctly, it makes KVM focus switching much more convenient.

But as a result, if a KVM is of the second type, the USB port on the KVM will no longer be fully general-purpose: the special handling for mouse and keyboard may confuse any other USB devices connected via the same ports. That's why some KVMs have dedicated ports for keyboard and mouse, *plus* a few general-purpose USB ports that are just switched between the connected computers when the KVM focus switches by "unplugging" them from one computer and "re-plugging" into another.

As a result, your question is not answerable with any certainty unless you specify the exact model of the KVM you're using, and which USB port of it you're using for your webcam.

Comment: The linked KVM claims to support more than just keyboards and mice, including webcams.

Comment: The KVM switch is a Startech SV231DD2DUA.  The keyboard and mouse are pugged into the keyboard and mouse labeled usb ports on the switch and the webcam is plugged into one of the other usb ports.  I've tried plugging it into each of the additional usb ports and neither allows the the webcam to work.  Each allows a different usb keyboard to work.